# Make String look like url in TableModel

Tags: java, string, swing, url, tablemodel

Hello im making a program and using `TableModel`. I have 6 column filed with string's. I want the sixth column string make it look like URL. When i mean look like URL , i mean turn it into blue and be underlined. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sun had a very good tutorial (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#modelchange) on cerating jtable. just go through it before you start. hope this tutorial will help you.
But below is my suggestion.

```
("<html><b><u>link</u></html>");

<html><b><a href="link">bold</a></b></html>
```

a similar kind of thing

However, I wouldn't recommend altering the data in your model just to effect display. Instead I would create a custom cell renderer which accomplishes this effect and set it on the table. You could either wrap your text in the HTML or manually set font color and style properties on the renderer to mimic html.

Now even if you were to include the url in the html you still can't click on it. There is no component in the table. You don't really want to go into edit mode when clicking on a url. You just want to open that link. To accomplish this you would add a mouse listener to the table itself. When you receive a click event, you would then programatically determine which cell it was over, go back to your model and get the url, and finally use other Java API calls to open that url.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write custom TableCellRenderer for your jtable. See this [link](http://java-swing-tips.blogspot.com/2009/02/hyperlink-in-jtable-cell.html).This may be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can simply create a string containing

```
<html>...</html>
```

and it will work. Just code your link inside the html tags as you would in html. You'll just have to add extra code if you want it to appear blue. I think:

```
<font color='blue'>
```

would do it